# Check file extension (htm) if not rename to htm

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to construct a PowerShell script to check file extensions in a folder and if not to rename extension to `.htm`. Putting this together is proving more difficult.

What I have is:

```psh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\GP_Services
set-location C:\GP_Services
$root = Get-ChildItem 
foreach($file) {
  $txtfile =".htm"
  $files = gci | Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".htm"}
  else (rename-item -newname) { $_.name + '.htm' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `else` to `Where-Object`. You need to check if the extension is *not* equal to `.htm` and rename the file matching that criterion:

```psh
Get-ChildItem |
  Where-Object { $_.Extension -ne '.htm' } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName + '.htm' }
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.extension -ne ".htm"} | Rename-Item -newname { $_.name + '.htm' }   final line works a treat.. thanks guys

Comment: So you want to append the extension instead of replacing it? In that case you may want to accept @arco444 answer instead of mine, provided he decides to undelete it.